# og:title/meta for wordpress login

Tags: wordpress, authentication, meta

I have an issue concerning my og:title/meta description of my wordpress page silex.solutions.

For the site itself, the meta title, description, etc. has been set right. But as soon as it is posted anywhere else, for example, on Facebook, the crawler reads the redirect that leads to silex.solutions/login.

I have found many instances where and how to edit the meta for pages, but none on how to edit the meta for the login.

Any ideas on how to set a custom meta for the login page?

Much appreciated,
Edgars

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [login_head()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_head) hook to add the custom meta tags